# "Project Target Framework Not Installed" when opening a web site in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I want to open an ASP.NET web site running on IIS 8.5 in Visual Studio 2013. I go to **Open → Web Site...** and navigate to the web application's folder. When I try to open it, I receive an error message saying

> The Web project "FolderName" is targeting ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0", which is not installed on this machine. To proceed, select an option below.

[image]

This web site has never been opened in Visual Studio before, so there is no project associated with it—no .csproj file to define the target framework. The directory contains an .aspx file, an aspx.cs file, an aspx.designer.cs file, and a web.config file. None of those define any framework to target.

There is also a **bin** directory, which contains a .pdb, a .dll, and a .dll.config. The .dll.config file is an XML file that *does* define a target framework, but the version is 4.5. These are the entire contents of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

So from where is Visual Studio determining that it's targeting .NET 2.0?

The only thing I could think of is that on the same machine there is a Visual Studio project with the same root folder name as the IIS web app (same subfolder name in a different branch of the directory tree from the IIS files). In fact, the web app was created by copying the code from the VS project. But the VS project's .csproj file targets .NET 4.5:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    [...] 
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    [...] 
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Also, there's no problem opening this project, so obviously VS doesn't think it's targeting a framework that's not installed. Nor is there any problem executing the web app.

Comment: BTW, I decided to take the plunge and click `OK` with the first radio button selected, `Change the target to .NET Framework 4.5`. But what is it changing? Where is the target defined as .NET 2.0 to begin with, and where does it change to being defined as .NET 4.5? VS creates a temporary project directory in my profile's Documents called **Visual Studio 2013\Projects\localhost_57273**, but this directory is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but for me the Framework version 4.6.1 was missing even though i had installed it and verified it using the [.NET Framework Setup Verification Tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/10/13/net-framework-setup-verification-tool-users-guide/)

i let it change the target one of my projects then had a look at the target frameworks in the dropdown. Version 4.6.1 was missing from that list.
i used the 'Install other frameworks' option in that list and used the one of the installers there. in my case i needed the developer pack.
After that all projects loaded fine.

[image: screenshot]